# Twitter's v2 endpoint - api.user_timeline (v1)

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

Do you know the equivalent of v1's function for v2?

I have  403 ERROR on this line

```
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name, count=200, tweet_mode='extended')
```

Do you have a suggestion for fix?

I am planning to retrieve all the tweets of a user.

My full code is here:

```
def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    file_name = os.path.join(output_dir, screen_name)
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name, count=200, tweet_mode='extended')
```